# Selenium with Python: how to increase resolution for full screen screenshot?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to increase the resolution of a full screen screenshot using Selenium with Python? I currently take screenshots the following way and the resolution appears to be low:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python27\chromedriver.exe')
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
browser.save_screenshot("savedImage.png")
```

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600245/how-to-capture-website-screenshot-in-high-resolution

Comment: I am already maximizing window size `browser.maximize_window()`. How is that solution going to help?

Comment: No you cannot save HD screenshots using selenium utility. It is going to capture a standard 1024x768 screenshot.

Comment: What can you use for this in Python when you browse web pages with Selenium?

Answer (score 4):

To take higher-DPI screenshots in Chrome selenium webdriver try using `--force-device-scale-factor` option as below:

```
desired_dpi = 2.0
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"--force-device-scale-factor={desired_dpi}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: this is work for me，but I think the "desired_dpi" should be "scale_factor"  and should be set to 1 or less 1.

Answer (score 0):

Set system "Scale and layout" to 100%, or add Chrome options:

```
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--force-device-scale-factor=1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

[image]